# Unable to scroll vertically with ion-scroll direction='x' in ionic

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

In side a page i have some content and after the content, i have a horizontally scrollable section, which will scroll horizontally. After that section, i have some other content.

The issue is, if i tap and scroll on the content, then i am able to scroll vertically. But if i tap and scroll on the horizontal scrolling section, i am unable to scroll vertically. `ion-scroll direction=x` is blocking the horizontal scroll. If the horizontal section takes almost full height of the screen, then the user is unable to scroll in vertical direction, which is blocking the scroll. If i remove `ion-scroll` and use custom css `overflow-x : scroll`, then i am able to scroll vertically by tapping on the horizontally scrollable section. But this is working in browser, but not in the mobile.

Please have a look at the code pen

http://codepen.io/rajeshwarpatlolla/pen/MwQaqB

HTML

```
<ion-content>
  <h1>heading</h1>
  <h1>heading</h1>
    <ion-scroll id="ionScrollRegion" direction="x">
      <div id="content">
        <div class="item" ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.data}}</div>
      </div>
    </ion-scroll>
  <h1>heading</h1>
  <h1>heading</h1>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Hello ! I have the same Issue ! have you found any solution for this ? thanks

Answer (score 9):

Yes @Yasser B, i found a solution.
Please have a look at the below link.

http://codepen.io/rajeshwarpatlolla/pen/xGWBja

HTML

```
<ion-scroll direction="x" zooming="false" delegate-handle="horizontal" horizontal-scroll-fix="mainScroll">
    //content
</ion-scroll>
```

If you have any queries, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing your solution. It's really beneficial to me.

Comment: It seems like your solution frequently run into error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
sv.mouseMove @ VM24752:12`

Comment: It was working fine. Is the behaviour working fine? If so you can use try catch block to avoid console errors. But the functionality should work fine.

Comment: Hi, yeah it's working. However, in the console log I frequently receive the error of `cannot read property 'apply'`. How to catch the block?

Comment: Not sure, but i was not getting any errors with it. Have you followed the exact procedure like using delegates as shown in the example. Like `horizontal-scroll-fix` and `delegate-handle`. They are used in the controllers too. Please cross check once again.

Comment: I fixed the error `cannot read property 'apply'` by checking to make sure the object existed before calling `apply()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use $ionicScrollDelegate to achieve your job.

assign delegate handler to "ion-content"

```
<ion-content delegate-handle="mainScroll">
```

handle scroll event on "ion-scroll" and change the direction to x & y.

```
<ion-scroll id="ionScrollRegion" direction="xy" on-scroll="vscroll(this.direction)">
```

And in Controller handle the vertical scroll event to scroll ion-content like given in code below. You can check "direction", parameter to check if vertical scroll is requested. If vertical scroll is requested you can scroll "ion-content" using deledate

```
$scope.vscroll = function(direction){
  alert(direction);
  //check if vertical scroll requested using direction parameter, if yes execute below line
  $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('mainScroll').scrollBottom();
}
```

Hope this will help

Comment: I tried your example in my code pen but still its not working. Could you please provide a codepen or plunkr link?

Comment: I don't want to scroll both in x and y directions. The scrolling should be in x direction only. Try clicking beside the heading and try to drag the page, you will be able to drag the page. But if you tap on the horizontal scrolling area, and try to drag the page up and down then you wont be able to move the page up and down. I need this to be fixed. Hope you understood.

Comment: Yes you don't want to scroll in y direction. It just to know user wants to scroll the outer content. When user try to scroll in y direction you can scroll the main ion-content.  check  this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJXEqe

Comment: Check this now. http://codepen.io/rajeshwarpatlolla/pen/EjQyOJ
If the height occupies the full screen height then, user wont be able to scroll up and down to see the content out side the ion-scroll. Try in mobile if possible u will get the difference.

Comment: I can not try it in mobile now, But though height occupies the full screen, as we have given xy direction to "ion-scroll" it will call the vscroll event. And in that event, you can scroll outer content up or down using $ionicScrollDelegate. In my example it is scrolling to bottom of the outer content, when you try to scroll inner content.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I would like to have only vertical scrolling. Ionic currently does not scroll automaticaly. Can someone please share (only necessary code) on codepan?

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a hack, but you can just prevent the preventDefault from being called (you can always save it as something else if you need it later).

Add the following as a directive of the scroll view.

```js
function horizontalScrollFix() {

  var directive = {
    link: link,
    restrict: 'A'
  };
  return directive;

  function link(scope, element, attrs) {

    element.children().on('mousedown touchstart', function(event){
      event.preventDefault = function(){};
    });

  }
}
```